# UIViewController won't respond to presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, self

I've had a UITableViewController-Class. I've changed the UITableViewController Class to UIVIewController and made and specified the connections in IB new.
Everything works fine, except `[self presentModalViewController:.....]`
The compiler says that self my not respond to "self" and the app crashes when rotating the view.

thanks for your help :)

SOLUTION: I haven't set the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" method in both views.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're calling the correct function? It's

```
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
```

Make sure not to forget the `animated:` parameter.  If you have, in fact, got that part in there, my only suggestion would be to make sure you've got the spelling correct and that that line of code in fact in the right class.

Comment: yep everything should be there:
GetItBack *getItBack = [[GetItBack alloc]init];  
getItBack = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;  
  [self presentModalViewController: getItBack Animated:YES];  
  [getItBack release];

Comment: animated was in capital letters not it doesn't crash anymore. the compiler keeps displaying the warning... Any hints?